# Replace xsi:nil="true" with empty tags in Xml Serialization C#

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, parsing, object, serialization

i am trying to serialize an mvc object to xml string

i am parsing the object using this function

```
public string ToXML(object oObject)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(oObject.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, oObject);
            xmlStream.Position = 0;
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
            return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately i want my xml schema to be like this for nullable values e.g

instead of `<fProjectGID xsi:nil="true" />`

be like

```
<fProjectGID><fProjectGID/>
```

How i can add a second tag and remove this silly xsi:nill="true" attribute from my generated xml for every nullable value ?

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(file);                           
XmlNode node = doc["Root"]["fProjectGID"]; \\ Go to your desired Node
node.RemoveAll(); \\It Will remove the  xsi:nil="true"
node.InnerText = " Put Here your desired text";  \\ Any Inner Text You want.
```